# Unable to get Json array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Guys i have tried to get the JSON array value through PHP. its not returning any value

```
{
"transactionTime": "2015-11-14T03:36:11-08:00",
"receipt": "********",

"lineItems": [
    {
        "itemNo": "1",

    }
],

}
```

in PHP i have tried this code

Here $decrypted contains the above formatted JSON value.

```
$order = json_decode($decrypted);
$id = $order['transactionTime'];
```

Could anyone look at it . thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$order = json_decode($decrypted, true);
$id = $order['transactionTime'];
```

**Edited**

When you set `assoc` parameter in `json_decode()` function to `TRUE`, the returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: I have removed the comma

$id = $order['lineItems']['itemNo'];

is that correct to get itemNo value ?? because its not getting the value..

Comment: yes, that's correct. That should give you the `itemNo`. By the way, as @n-dru pointed out, your json is incorrect, please remove the trailing comma after `"itemNo": "1"` and after final `]`. You can validate your json [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: You json is valid, and oh! I was wrong, since `lineItems` is an array, this is what you would do to get `itemNo`, `$id = $order['lineItems'][0]['itemNo'];`.

Comment: Happy to hear. Please upvote and accept the answer. :)

Comment: Hey buddy
$cbemail   = $order['customer']['billing']['email']; doesnot return any value ??

Comment: I checked this code on my system and it's working fine for me. When I do `$cbemail = $order['customer']['billing']['email']; echo $cbemail;`, it shows `testuser@somesite.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is invalid - remove trailing comma after `"itemNo": "1"` and after final `]`.

Comment: Here the complete string textuploader.com/56wwg